# Reading double in C from binary unsigned char* with specified endianness

Tags: c, binary, double, decode

I have written a MariaDB/MySQL UDF in C for working with spatial data.  I data is available to the function as an unsigned char*.  The binary encoding of the data begins with a toggle bit signalling whether the stream is encoded little endian or big endian.  Since this is the case I have used the following macros to read the unsigned 32 bit ints from the stream:

```
#define U32BIT_LE_DATA(ptr) (*(ptr)<<0) | (*(ptr + 1)<<8) | (*(ptr + 2)<<16) | (*(ptr + 3)<<24)
#define U32BIT_BE_DATA(ptr) (*(ptr + 3)<<0) | (*(ptr + 2)<<8) | (*(ptr + 1)<<16) | (*(ptr)<<24)
    
uint32_t var = U32BIT_LE_DATA(ptr); // Little endian encoding
uint32_t var = U32BIT_BE_DATA(ptr); // Big endian encoding
```

The stream also has doubles that I need to parse (64-bit (8 byte) double-precision data using the IEEE 754 double-precision format).  I know I can do:

```
double var;
memcpy(&var, ptr, sizeof(double));
```

But this code is not very safe in regards to portability.  I am aware that if I know my machines endiannes, then I can simply reverse the order of the bytes before calling `memcpy`. Nevertheless, is there a more reliable way to decode a double from or encode it to a 64bit IEEE 754 double-precision floating point using a specified endianness without needing to know the endianness (and system specific double layout) of the machine running the code?

Comment: If you know your machine's `double` is also IEEE 754 double precision, you could first read the bytes as a `uint64_t` with endian conversion, and then either `memcpy` it to a `double` or indulge in a bit of unsafe aliasing via a `union` type.

Comment: What is the approximate volume of data (gigabytes or petabytes)?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, nice!  Perhaps you will have a good chuckle, the binary data is on the order of several kilobytes to maybe a few megabytes.

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef union 
{
    double d;
    uint8_t b[sizeof(double)];
}u64;

inline double toDoubleLE(const uint8_t *arr, int endianess)
{
    u64 u;
    if (endianess)
    {
        for(size_t x = 0; x < sizeof(u); x++)
        {
            u.b[sizeof(u) - x - 1] = arr[x];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for(size_t x = 0; x < sizeof(u); x++)
        {
            u.b[x] = arr[x];
        }
    }
    return u.d;
}

double fooLE(uint8_t *arr)
{
    return toDoubleLE(arr, 0);
}

double foobE(uint8_t *arr)
{
    return toDoubleLE(arr, 1);
}
```

compilers are "smart" and x86-64 will convert it to 2 machine code operations.

```
fooLE:
        movzx   eax, BYTE PTR [rdi]
        movq    xmm0, rax
        ret
foobE:
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rdi]
        bswap   rax
        movq    xmm0, rax
        ret
```

https://godbolt.org/z/ofpDGe

Comment: You forgot to define `u64` in the above.

Comment: @IanAbbott indeed :)

Comment: Thanks for the info about the compiler.  Just to be clear, with this sort of approach I need to check the endianness of my system to right?  I assume I could just check the endianness of the system against the endianness of the stream, and just use memcpy if they are the same, and use this byte array reversing trick if they differ (doesn't really matter which direction).  Is that right?

Comment: Only if your code is going to be compiled to be executed on many hardware architectures. If it is for PC you can assume the little endian

Answer (score 0):

> Nevertheless, is there a more reliable way to decode a double from or encode it to a 64bit IEEE 754 double-precision floating point

On POSIX or Unix systems, connsider using [XDR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_Data_Representation) or [ASN/1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASN.1).

If the data is not too big, consider [JSON](https://json.org/) (e.g. with [Jansson](https://digip.org/jansson/)) or perhaps [YAML](https://yaml.org/) and decide to represent it in textual form. Read then carefully the documentation of [fscanf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) and [fprintf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) (e.g. related to `%a` format specifier).

See also the [floating-point-gui.de](https://floating-point-gui.de/)

Comment: Thank you for the pointers, I never know about XDR and ASN/1.  Pretty neat stuff.  I have done a lot with JSON/YAML and some work with fscanf/fprintf.  Funny enough I had thought binary streams to be vastly superior for a long time, till I started dealing with these concerns.  Sadly, like so many things in life, I have no control over the generated binary data.